# Clear location state after navigating to some path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router `browserHistory` to navigate to path.

```
browserHistory.push({
  pathname: '/mycomponent',
  state: { someValue: 'value'},
});
```

So this will navigate to mycomponent. As soon as i reach to mycomponent i want to clear key `someValue`. so that when i refresh the page it won't contain that value.

```
export class myComponent extends component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const value = this.props.location.state.someValue;
    // clear state.someValue from history
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: afaik `someValue` won't be in the location state after you refresh the page. So you don't need to manually remove it.

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara - I could see it even after page refresh..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think that you can use browserHistory `replace` method to replace history state with new one without `someValue` defined:

```
export class myComponent extends component {
    componentWillMount() {
        const value = this.props.location.state.someValue;
       // clear state.someValue from history
        browserHistory.replace({
           pathname: '/mycomponent',
           state: {}
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `history.replace()` to clear the state, this way:

Just
`import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';`

And then `const history = useHistory();`

Finally:

```
useEffect(() => {
  history.replace();
}, []);
```

Comment: I've been using the state prop from Link to send an object from one page to another. I then use that variable as a parameter to set the destination page state, and then I'm just setting `location.state` to `null`. Since I'm not really concerned with clearing history, is this okay?